# Where can I find information on existing viruses?

Tags: malware, virus

As part of my research, I have created a small malware corpus which I'm conducting my tests against. I would like to categorize them based on Metamorphic / Polymorphic / etc.

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question. If not, I would appreciate suggestions for a more suitable one.

Comment: Not clear what you're looking for.  [Anti-virus sites](http://home.mcafee.com/virusinfo/) will supply extensive information about viruses, including metamorphic/polymorphic.etc.  If you want to classify them against some novel scheme, you'd need a large corpus of samples, and I don't think this is the right place to ask that.  (I'm not endorsing McAfee, that was just a random example).

Comment: @ Mark- Thanks for the reply. At present, my corpus contains about 10g of malwares. I am not interested in expanding it at the moment. My machine learning alg' depends on the ability to differentiate metamorphic / non-metamorphic malwares, so I'm looking for a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

VX heaven (which is now unfortunately down) used to be a great source for research materials.  You can probably still find some places where they have some of the documentation and malware examples they provided (Google is you friend here).

[Malware Sample Sources for Researchers](http://zeltser.com/combating-malicious-software/malware-sample-sources.html) has some malware's sources which can be studied to understand how they infect computers and spread.

The information you will find should be only used for educational purposes though.

Answer (score 1):

[Malware.lu](http://www.malware.lu/) is a repository of malware and technical analyses. The goal of the project is to provide samples and technical analyses to security researchers.

Answer (score 0):

In my work, I classified my sample-set using 14 anti-virus log. Although No anti-virus could classified properly(detection was too low) [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6207739) My database consist of 3000+ viruses. (it  worked)